# Wordpress cron job, CSV file import size

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

So I'm using WP-Cron and this is my php cron job I'm running the problem is file size I can't figure out how to handle the file size its huge a little over a 1gb I believe. https://data.medicare.gov/api/views/mj5m-pzi6/rows.csv this is the CSV file here.

```
       $args = array(
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any'
        );

        $ids = get_posts($args);

        foreach($ids as $id) {
            wp_delete_post($id->ID, true);
        }
        header("Content-type: text/csv");
        $csv = file_get_contents('https://data.medicare.gov/api/views/mj5m-pzi6/rows.csv');

        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);
        $array = array();

        foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
        }
        for ($i=1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if($array[$i][0] == '') {
            $ad1 = 'Null';
        } else {
            $ad1 = $array[$i][0];
        }

        if($array[$i][1] == '') {
            $ad2 = 'Null';
        } else {
            $ad2 = $array[$i][1];
        }

        $content = "Address 1: ".$ad1." Address 2: ".$ad2."</br>";


        $post = array(
            'post_title' => $ad1,
            'post_content' => $content,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => 1
        );
        wp_insert_post($post);
        }
```

Comment: this is written terrible. really.  Poor use of memory. `file_get_contents` I would read it one line at a time with `fgetcsv` just saying.  If it was my code I would have to rewrite it....  What does `wp_delete_post` have to do with the CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This should be more efficient

I tried rewriting this bit. The original just wasn't savable, but I tried to keep it functionally equivalent.

```
$csv = file_get_contents();

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);
$array = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
for ($i=1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if($array[$i][0] == '') {
        $ad1 = 'Null';
    } else {
        $ad1 = $array[$i][0];
    }

    if($array[$i][1] == '') {
        $ad2 = 'Null';
    } else {
        $ad2 = $array[$i][1];
    }

    $content = "Address 1: ".$ad1." Address 2: ".$ad2."</br>";


    $post = array(
        'post_title' => $ad1,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1
    );
    wp_insert_post($post);
}
```

But without any data to look at, and not really knowing what that top part of the script has to do with any of this, this is the best I can do.  Also there are a few nesting levels in there I just refuse to use.

```
$handle = fopen('https://data.medicare.gov/api/views/mj5m-pzi6/rows.csv', 'r');
while(!feof($handle)){
    $line = fgetcsv($handle);
    /*
      the original has this $array[$i][0], $array[$i][1] we don't have the 
      $i level so this is just the first/second columns

      {condition} ? true : false - these are ternary statements which are
      just a way of doing a shorthand if condition.
    */
    $ad1 = ($line[0] == '') ? 'Null' : $line[0];
    $ad2 = ($line[1] == '') ? 'Null' : $line[1];

    /*
      you might want to add this check in, continue will skip to the next
      iteration, the if checks if both ad1 and ad2 are 'Null` so these look
      to me to be empty rows, so just un-comment that to skip them
    */
    //if($ad1 == 'Null' && $ad2 == 'Null') continue;

    $content = "Address 1: ".$ad1." Address 2: ".$ad2."</br>";

    //short hand array syntax PHPv5.4+ 
    $post = [
        'post_title' => $ad1,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1
    ];
    wp_insert_post($post);
}
```

It's not a big deal as it took me like 10 minutes.  Hope it works for you, I can't test it.  You may notice it's much shorter then the original.

> HyYa I'm like a code ninja with them half-chops.

The key here, is the original opens the whole file into memory. Then it explodes it into a massive array, then it iterates though it not once but 2x. Then it does the inserting.

My version, pulls each line separately, checks it, does the insert, dumps it from memory.  This is obviously much better on memory management.  You should not run out of memory with this version.

That said you may still run out of time. You can add something like this.

```
while(!feof($handle)){
    set_time_limit(60); //1 minutes per iteration
```

Of course you can just set `set_time_limit(0);` or unlimited time.

However, Apache's timeout will most likely get you, as I think WP-Cron doesn't actually use CRON. Or in other words doesn't run on the Command Line (CLI). But I like giving it a limit based on the iteration then it's not infinite.  Essentially this says as long as this iteration takes less then 1 minute don't timeout.  But as I said I don't think this is a "true" Cron job.  It's more of a scheduler that runs in wordpress and because of that your still tied to the Apache server.

There is probably a way to tie it into a real Cron Job, but now I am rambling and it's not really important at this time (I'm not a big Wordpress user)

**A few last things**

**1**

This looks like a remote file `https://`, you might get better performance if you save it first then go though it.  But I wouldn't worry about that unless you have network issues, because then you are doing double duty. However if you have problems reading it line by line than I would suggest,  using something like `stream_copy_to_stream` to write it to disk faster without the DB inserts, then go though it again after saving it, and then delete the file with `unlink`

```
 $remote = fopen('https://...', 'r');
 $local  = fopen('localfile.css', 'w+'); //write/read mode

 stream_copy_to_stream($remote, $local);

 fclose($remote);
 rewind($local); //rewind file pointer to start
 ...other code..
```

This way you have the whole file locally before starting, but it should be clear why I said it's double duty.

**2**

I am not sure what this has to do with the CSV part, it seems like it's a separate deal.

```
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any'
    );

    $ids = get_posts($args);

    foreach($ids as $id) {
        wp_delete_post($id->ID, true);
    }
```

It's best to keep a script focused on one task, it makes things easier to maintain.  Maybe it is part of this?  I just don't see any variables binding it to the CSV part and there is some code missing at the top. So I just ignored it and focused on the CSV part.

**3**

This header is only need if you are outputting the contents for something like a download.  This tells the browser what time of content it is, and if your not giving it to the browser by outputting it then it's at best unnecessary, at worst it will cause errors if you try to do certain things after sending the headers.  Like redirects, but I don't see that happening in this use case.

```
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
```

**Summery**

Don't take anything I said in the wrong tone, people tend to do that with me. I'm just very blunt when it comes to critiquing code.  Everyone has to learn and I literally work at a place where we read CSV files that can get into the 10's of megabytes.  The biggest one we ever did was 15million rows and we routinely read files with  around 1 million rows.

We use SPLFileObject as a base for our CSV reader, it's very cool but probably a bit overkill to setup for this. In any case this is probably the most efficient way to read CSV without getting into anything to crazy.

Feel free to ask if you have any question on how it works..

### UPDATE

You should really run this with the real CRON

[What is the Real CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

It's a bit of an advanced topic, and wordpress doesn't make it any easier.  I could write a whole other post on just that.  But it runs PHP from the CLI command line interface, which bypasses some of the limits of running under Apache (like the timelimit).

It will be a bit of a trick to get WP to run in that way but I put together a few things I googled and some is from personal knowledge.

Run wordpresss outside of the webroot (outside of public_html) From the CLI, will assume this is in a folder named `/home/website/cron` which is a sibling of the webroot `/home/website/public_html`

```
<?php
     //make sure error reporting is on
     error_reporting(-1);
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
     $webreoot = realpath('../public_html').'/';
    
    //setup global $_SERVER variables to emulate Apache environment
    $_SERVER = array(
      "HTTP_HOST" => "http://example.com",
      "SERVER_NAME" => "http://example.com",
      "REQUEST_URI" => "/",
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET",
      "SERVER_ADDR" => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
    );

    //turn off theme support
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    //require the WP bootstrap
    require_once $webreoot.'wp-load.php';

   //wordpress should in theory be loaded where you can use the wp_ functions.
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The first part of my code I included it because its in involved wordpress, simply I'm deleting all post before inserting new ones. I really appreciate the time you spent writing on this, I was kinda thinking about some how I could divide things up and make it easy. I did test the script but it only inserted 13 thousand rows, so now I'm adding a time_limit and testing it that way, their is slightly over 100 thousand rows.

Comment: My only problem after testing is that I'm running out of execution time but I think I'll figure it out.

Comment: I'm mostly a web designer, the client needed help so I don't know how he's going to host it. I'm going to ask him because I know the script can parse the csv properly but wordpress can't handle it.

Comment: I added a small update, but I'm afraid to explain that will be too much to try to put on  here.

Comment: I used to be a web developer, then I was a Sr Developer, now I am a CIO, Chief Information Officer, in charge of a small Development team.

Comment: I'm actually having some very weird problems now, its skipping rows in the CSV I'm going to take a break and think about it.